# Finder windows moving from other monitors as soon as the computer hibernates

Tags: finder, mojave, hibernate

I have 3 monitors. I have finder opened with windows on monitor 1, 2 and 3. The middle one, 2, is the main screen on the iMac.

As soon as the computer hibernates, the windows on other monitors are moved to the main monitor. This is pretty much annoying.

Attention because I am not talking about applications on other monitors. I have Photoshop on 3 and Pages on 1 and those never moves.

The problem is with Finder windows only.

This is my Spaces config.

[image]

This problem started on Mojave.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this apple discussion thread about your issue:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7729597)

> First you need to open Mission Control and add a new "Spaces" now just
>   called a "Desktops" to both screens. You don't need to use these new
>   Desktops, they just need to be there. With two monitors you end up
>   with "Desktop 1" and "Desktop 2" on the first monitor and "Desktop 3"
>   and Desktop 4" on the second monitor.
>
> Right click the Dock Icon for that application you want to launch in
>   the second screen and choose Option. Now you can assign the
>   Application to always open on the second Desktop.
>
> Without having multiple Desktops established, this option isn't
>   available. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: BRILLIANT! I have read this solution before in the web but this time I have noticed that you have to have two desktops per monitor. I had one. That solved the problem. thank you and thanks apple for making this shitty.